# handle RSVP.Hash errors from model hook

Tags: ember.js, rsvp.js

Say I am returning an RSVP.Hash from a model hook like this:

```
model: function() {
  hash = {
    users: App.User.find(),
    contacts: App.Contact.find()
  };

  return Ember.RSVP.hash(hash);
}
```

This works fine for me in the good case but what about the bad case where one of them returns something other than an http 200?  How can I handle errors in this scenario?

Comment: Hello, any luck with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to have more granular control over errors when using promise composing functions you can use `Ember.RSVP.allSettled` and `Ember.RSVP.hashSettled`.

related docs and examples:

- https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/blob/2c2975fdd2e530c44ca3cda9cbcfd14208cc0e8d/lib/rsvp/hash-settled.js#L21-L121
- https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/blob/2c2975fdd2e530c44ca3cda9cbcfd14208cc0e8d/lib/rsvp/all-settled.js#L17-L67